# JDBC connection url in spring bean for sqlserver instance

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

i am using

```
> org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
```

with Version 4 of

```
`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`
```

trying to connect to a 2014 SqlServer. 
I'm trying to connect to a specific instance running on that server.
I can't figure out the right url for this connection.

This is my config in the spring.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.securess.jdbc.jdbcsample"></context:component-scan>
       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://myhost\\\myinstance:myport;databasename=mydb"/>
            <property name="username" value="myadmin"/>
            <property name="password" value="mypwd"/>           
            <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
            <property name="maxTotal" value="2"/>
       </bean>
```

I get an SQLException:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: 
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: 
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory 
(Fehler beim Herstellen der TCP/IP-Verbindung mit dem Host 'hostname', Port portnumber. Fehler: 'Connection refused: connect. 
Überprüfen Sie die Verbindungseigenschaften. 
Stellen Sie sicher, dass eine SQL Server-Instanz auf dem Host ausgeführt wird und am Port TCP/IP-Verbindungen akzeptiert. 
Vergewissern Sie sich, dass am Port keine TCP-Verbindungen durch eine Firewall blockiert werden.'.)
```

Any clues out there?

Thanks.

Comment: So, you are using a named instance, right?

Comment: Hi Alfabravo, that is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had quite a few tries and errors. Found out that the portnumber wasn't accepted. Finally i got this config working quite nicely:

> ```
>    <context:component-scan base-package="com.securess.jdbc.jdbcsample"></context:component-scan>
>    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
>           <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
>           <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://myhost;instanceName=myinstance;databaseName=mydb"/>
>       <property name="username" value="sa"/>
>           <property name="password" value="mypwd"/>           
>           <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
>           <property name="maxTotal" value="5"/>
>    </bean>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Backslah in a String, you have to escape it.

And you have to provide some Authentication information. Example from [Klick me](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-microsoft-sql-server-via-jdbc):

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlexpress;user=sa;password=secret";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
```

Comment: Hello Pastafari,
i have provided login credentials in spring.xml. i also have tested masking backslash. same error. any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try the double Backslash?

Comment: hi, yes i tried this as well. 
i provided details about my spring.xml in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Its bad the url of connection or user or password or driver, check if the connection is ok in other way.